# how to update table using trigger

Tags: mysql

i am new to this and want some help.i have table with name "abc" with following entries

```
+------+--------+------+
| Id   | Name   | City |
+------+--------+------+
|  101 | john   | abc  |
|  102 | Miller | cbz  |
+------+--------+------+
```

and another table "xyz"

```
+------+--------+------+
| Id   | Name   | City |
+------+--------+------+
|  102 | Miller | cbz  |
+------+--------+------+
```

i applied trigger on table "abc" which will update the table "xyz" with recently inserted values and will delete all previous entries...
for example, when i fire insert query on "abc" table i get ,"abc" as follow

```
  insert into abc Values(103,'Joseph','xyz');
```

i get output for table "abc" as,

```
 +------+--------+------+
 | Id   | Name   | City |
 +------+--------+------+
 |  101 | john   | abc  |
 |  102 | Miller | cbz  |
 |  103 | Joseph | xyz  |
 +------+--------+------+
```

and table "xyz" as,

```
  +------+--------+------+
  | Id   | Name   | City |
  +------+--------+------+
  |  103 | Joseph | xyz  |
  +------+--------+------+
```

now my question is how to acheive this using only one table(i dont want to use two table as this is not my requirement).
like following ..

```
    insert into xyz values(104,'Ridhit','pqr');

  +------+--------+------+
  | Id   | Name   | City |
  +------+--------+------+
  |  104 | Ridhit | pqr  |
  +------+--------+------+
```

Please help.Trigger i used is

```
  DELIMITER !!
  create trigger OnlyOne BEFORE INSERT on abc
  for each row
  BEGIN
  DECLARE a1 INT;
      Select count(1) INTO a1 from xyz;
   IF a1>0 THEN
    delete from xyz limit 1;
    insert into xyz(Id,Name,City) values (new.Id,new.Name,new.City);
   ELSE
    insert into xyz(Id,Name,City) values (new.Id,new.Name,new.City);
   END IF;
   END;
   !!
   DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Did you mean you will insert on `xyz` and it will delete previous entry before adding the new ? If so this is not possible with trigger. You can not do insert/update/delete on the same table where trigger is done.

Comment: ohh :(...so any other solution...?

Comment: May be you need to do it within the application level.

Comment: okay i will do as u said.. thanks Abhik.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this on application level, but you better make sure you use [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). You probably don't want to have an empty table, when the operation crashes in the middle.

You may also consider to have following approach.

Instead of deleting/updating whenever an insert occurs, add a column like created with default value of current timestamp to your table so that it looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE abc(
id int auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(50),
city varchar(50),
created timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

To get the latest entry you just do

```
SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Or you put this in a view

```
CREATE VIEW just_latest_entry_from_abc AS
SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then you just do

```
SELECT * FROM just_latest_entry_from_abc;
```

When table size matters, create a cronjob or a [scheduled event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) to delete older entries on a regular basis.

Comment: agree with your solution but this will give only last entry...what if, if user insert multiple entries...?

Comment: Then go with the first solution, but use transactions.